# Error in SDL2 when Building for Android with ndk-build

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, sdl, ndk-build

I have gotten to the point of attempting to compile SDL2 for Android with ndk-build. However, I seem to be getting errors when compiling the unedited SDL2-2.0.3 source code for some of the files. I have turned on ndk-build's `-k` compiler switch which allows me to keep building even after errors have occured, but several files seem to be causing errors in compilation.

Below are some of the messages from the compiler caused by the erroneous files:

```
C:/android_dev/SDL2-2.0.3/android-project/jni/SDL2/src/SDL_error.c:95:39: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
                     const char *str = va_arg(ap, const char *);
                                       ^
make.exe: *** [C:/android_dev/SDL2-2.0.3/android-project/obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2/src/SDL_error.o] Error 1
```

---

```
C:/android_dev/SDL2-2.0.3/android-project/jni/SDL2/src/stdlib/SDL_string.c:985:5: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of 'vsscanf'
     return vsscanf(text, fmt, ap);
```

---